# Test hbase using ycsb on arm machine throws error

Tags: hbase, ycsb

When I test hbase using ycsb I get the following error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ClassSize
     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.(IPCUtil.java:74)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.  
      (AbstractRpcClient.java:91)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.
        (RpcClientImpl.java:1082)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.(RpcClientImpl.java:1108)
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error does not look related to YCSB, whatever you are doing - please ensure that hbase-common jar is in your classpath.

Comment: I use ambari to deploy hbase,and use ycsb to test hbase.Then appear problems: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Constructor threw an exception for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:54)